# O que está errado neste código?

Tags: c++

Por que este código não está sendo compilado?

```
#include <iostream>
using namesapace std;
int main(){
long long xm;
long long ym;
long long xp;
long long yp;
cin>>xm;
cin>>ym;
cin>>xp;
cin>>yp;
long long t;
t=(xp+yp)-(xm+ym);
cout<<t<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Geralmente o próprio compilador te diz isso, basta ler a mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só um erro de digitação `namespace` está escrito errado. Isto ocorre porque o código está escrito de qualquer jeito. Se escrever um cuidado, capricho fica mais fácil evitar esses erros e detectá-los mais facilmente.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    long long xm;
    long long ym;
    long long xp;
    long long yp;
    cin >> xm;
    cin >> ym;
    cin >> xp;
    cin >> yp;
    long long t = (xp + yp) - (xm + ym);
    cout << t << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dTKUBT). Veja [funcionando no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dikwbeqs-maniero). Também [coloquei no GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Namespace.cpp).